# Spring Boot, /actuator return Resource not found in Console

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-boot-actuator

Below mentioned are my `pom.xml`, `application.yml` and logs. All the `/actuator` & `/actuator/*` endpoints reverts back to a login page. [Please find here the login page screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTBGl.png)

There is a different application for tracking the admin. So admin dependencies are for that only.

Pom.xml :

```
<project>
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <relativePath/>
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.application.application-name</groupId>
    <artifactId>application-name</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>application-name</name>
    <description> service for handling the events</description>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-boot-admin.version>2.4.0</spring-boot-admin.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot-admin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Application-dev.yml:

```
security.basic.enabled: false

server:
  port: ${PORT:8087}
spring:
  application:
    name: XYZ
  boot:
    #   https://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/current/#spring-boot-admin-client
    admin:
      api-path: /instances
      client:
        auto-registration: true
        auto-deregistration: true
        register-once: true
        url: "http://localhost:9090"
        instance:
          name: XYZ
        username: superadmin
        password: admin
  security:
    filter:
      dispatcher-types: async,forward,request,error
    user:
      name: superadmin
      password: admin

logging:
  level:
#    root: ${ROOT_LOGGING_LEVEL:DEBUG}
    org:
      apache:
        kafka: ERROR
#      de:
#        codecentric:
#          boot:
#            admin:
#              client:
#                registration: DEBUG

management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
        exclude: heapdump
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: always
    metrics:
      enabled: true
    security:
      enabled: true
    shutdown:
      enabled: true
  health:
    mail:
      enabled: false
  server:
    port: 8087
```

Logs:

```
2022-04-12 17:21:52.701  INFO 568530 --- [nio-8087-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-04-12 17:21:52.701  INFO 568530 --- [nio-8087-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-04-12 17:21:52.701 DEBUG 568530 --- [nio-8087-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected StandardServletMultipartResolver
2022-04-12 17:21:52.701 DEBUG 568530 --- [nio-8087-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver
2022-04-12 17:21:52.701 DEBUG 568530 --- [nio-8087-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected FixedThemeResolver
2022-04-12 17:21:52.702 DEBUG 568530 --- [nio-8087-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator@139c2be3
2022-04-12 17:21:52.702 DEBUG 568530 --- [nio-8087-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager@37badac
2022-04-12 17:21:52.702 DEBUG 568530 --- [nio-8087-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : enableLoggingRequestDetails='false': request parameters and headers will be masked to prevent unsafe logging of potentially sensitive data
2022-04-12 17:21:52.702  INFO 568530 --- [nio-8087-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
2022-04-12 17:21:52.716 DEBUG 568530 --- [nio-8087-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/actuator", parameters={}
2022-04-12 17:21:52.725 DEBUG 568530 --- [nio-8087-exec-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler ["classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/", "/"]
2022-04-12 17:21:52.726 DEBUG 568530 --- [nio-8087-exec-1] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Resource not found
2022-04-12 17:21:52.727 DEBUG 568530 --- [nio-8087-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
2022-04-12 17:25:01.621 DEBUG 568530 --- [nio-8087-exec-8] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/actuator/health", parameters={}
2022-04-12 17:25:01.623 DEBUG 568530 --- [nio-8087-exec-8] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler ["classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/", "/"]
2022-04-12 17:25:01.625 DEBUG 568530 --- [nio-8087-exec-8] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Resource not found
2022-04-12 17:25:01.625 DEBUG 568530 --- [nio-8087-exec-8] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
```

Also, This is my security config for the application:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;


@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override

    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {

        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/actuator/**");
    }


}
```

Have I forgotten something to add or I'm doing something wrong?
Please help me out on this as it is really important for me to resolve.

Comment: Change `include: "*"` to `include: *`

Comment: That will throw an error then. Faeem

Comment: what error you get

Answer (score 0):

By default, all actuator endpoints are secured.
In the application-dev.yml file, you need to disable the security for actuator endpoints.

```
management:
   security:
      enabled: false
```

If problem still persists, try to expose the endpoints you need manually:

```
management:
    endpoints:
        web:
            exposure:
                include: [health,actuator,info]
```

A hude drawback of using yml files: indentation. Try to use `application.properties` file instead. More readable and unnecessary hassle free.

Comment: I tried that also, It throws the same 404 -No resource found.

Comment: Yeah, I Agreed. But Can't do anything on that. have to use only yml files only.

Comment: try to expose the endpoints you need manually----
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health,actuator,info

Comment: I have tried as aforementioned. Still the same issue is there.

Comment: I've used exact your yml and pom.xml file in a dummy program with Same Security config you've mentioned. That is working fine.  I'm pretty much sure the issue is with the implementation of admin application probably of which you have not given proper information. I need to see how that admin module is working using the same properties file